# Use custom Environment in Symfony Command

Tags: php, symfony, command-line

I try to run a command with some custom parameters i put in my `config_staging.yml` file.

Here is the parameter i would like to get (located in my config_staging)

```
parameters:
  bdd_name: 'ISB_bdd'
```

The same parameter is also in the config_dev (It's the db name, it changed for every env)

```
parameters:
  bdd_name: 'DEV_ISB_bdd'
```

And that's the code in my command file:

```
<?php
namespace SafeEngine\ParserFluxBundle\Command;

use [..]


class GetFluxToProcessCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
  protected function configure()
  {
      $this
          ->setName('parser:GetFluxToProcess')
       [...]
        );
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $tableTransactions = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('ISB_bdd');
    var_dump($tableTransactions):

[...]
```

Then i run

```
php app/console parser:GetFluxToProcess -e staging
```

But the var_dump returns `DEV_ISB_bdd`, the paramater in the `dev` config file, not the one in the `staging` config. It looks like Symfony don't switch environment and keep the default one,

Any idea?

Comment: You should add such parameters in config.yml which gets called in all environments.

Comment: and you sure that the `bdd_name` gets returned for that `ISB_TRANSACTIONS`? isn't that `DEV_ISB_bdd` appears anywhere else? In `parameters.*` maybe?

Comment: @ApulGupta nop, i have to switch the bdd name for each env

Comment: @fejese my bad, it was a copy/paste mistake :)

Comment: Did you clear your cache for dev and for staging environments?

Comment: What and where are the imports in your staging config file? Sure you don't include the dev config after trying to define the parameter by any chance?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov i got an error when clearing the cache, some perms issue.

Comment: @fejese Yeah i'm sure i don't import some param i other way than $this->getContainer()->getParameter('ISB_bdd');

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your cache and logs directories writable. To do so read the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup. For example for systems with ACL support you can use:

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

After that clear your cache and you will have updated configuration file for your staging environment.